# Case statement with braces

Tags: c, switch-statement

Why does a `case` statement allow declarations within braces but not without them?

For example, the following is  not OK

```
switch (op->name) {
    case 0:
        int a = 2;
    case 1:  
        int b = 3;
}
```

But the following is OK:

```
switch (op->name) {
    case 0: 
       {int a = 2;}
    case 1:  
       {int b = 3;}
}
```

What does the braces resolve that, without them, a declaration would be ambiguous to the compiler? To me (a beginner in C) it seems like each case statement should have an implied braces until the next case/default/end-of-switch, but that is obviously wrong!

Comment: In C, variables must be declared at the start of a block. Curly braces begin a new block. `case` labels do not create "implied braces".

Comment: *"In C, variables must be declared at the start of a block."* @RaymondChen That was the rule in C89. Not true in C99 and later.

Comment: @user3386109 but they **have** to declared inside the block

Comment: @ samuelbrody1249 You *do* need an opening brace after the `switch` statement in snippets 2 and 3.

Comment: @user3386109 sorry that was a typo -- fixed.

Comment: Snippet 2 is ok, but snippet 3 results in an error message (at least from clang) at the line that declares `b`.

Comment: @user3386109 yes it seems it errors, I suppose the braces cannot extend beyond a single `case`. Anyways, I've removed that case from the question since it's wrong.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Ok, the question seems in fine shape now. BTW, you *can* "fix" the problem by adding a superfluous semicolon after every `case` statement, e.g. `case 0: ;` My best guess is that the rule about not following a `case` statement with a declaration is due to some nasty corner case in the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does a case statement allow declarations within braces but not without them?

My compiler emits this error message:

> ```
> error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement
> ```

That's pretty clear I think.  Labels, including case labels, are not considered independent statements or declarations, but rather components of statements.  When control branches to a label, whether via a `switch` or a `goto`, it is the statement of which the label is a part to which the program jumps.  Not to the label itself, which typically has no runtime representation.

Declarations such as `int a;` are not statements, and labels cannot be part of declarations.  On the other hand, blocks such as `{ int a; }` *are* statements, and as statements, they can have labels.

There's no fundamental underlying constraint here.  It would have been possible for C syntax to have been defined differently, so that both of your examples were valid.  It just wasn't.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is invalid:

```
switch (op->name) {
    case 0:
        int a = 2;
    case 1:  
        int b = 3;
}
```

Is because you have a **label** (in this case a `case` label) in front of a **declaration**.  A label may only appear before a **statement**.

Using braces works because they are used to denote a **compound statement**, which is a particular type of statement, and a statement can immediately precede a label.

Formally, a label is part of a **labeled statement**.  This is spelled out in section 6.8.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> ```
> labeled-statement:
>   identifier : statement
>   case constant-expression : statement
>   default : statement
> ```

Comment: thanks for this. What is an example of `identifier : statement` ?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 That's a "regular" label that could be the subject of a `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and you'll get no error:

```
switch (op->name) {
    case 0:; /* <--- that ; is essential, see below */
        int a = 2;
    case 1:; /* <--- the same here. */
        int b = 3;
}
```

The problem is that the `case` *statement* is a special case of *statement*, but a *declaration* is not a valid substitute of a *statement*, so a *declaration* is not allowed immediately after a `case` label.  But you can always end the *case_statement* with a semicolon (issuing a *null statement*), and put your declaration right after it.